# How to add audio on clicking an image in gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, audio, gridview

I'm struggling with using gridview in android.
I want to create a layout with pictures of some animals so when you click on one of those images there will be the sound that the animal in the picture does. (for example, when you click on image of a cow you will hear "moooo..." ).
I didnt find a tutorial of using audio with gridview.
Can you help me please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `OnClickListener` for every `ImageView` inside your `GridView`. Then to play sound when `ImageView` is clicked implement in it's `OnClickListener` `onClick`:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.your_sound_file);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp=null;
            }
        });
mp.start();
```